# Hide, but not remove, specific category on the page with Divi & Tickera

Tags: wordpress

I have event categories from Tickera plugin shown with dynamic content from Divi as you can see here :

http://ktipnkf.cluster028.hosting.ovh.net/evenement/college-a-la-scene-pinocchio-de-joel-pommerat/

THEATRE and THEATRE MANSART

I know the event_category ID of the one I want to hide is 49 and I tried some code snippet to put in functions.php but nothing seems to work.

Is it possible to just not display it without exclude it ?

Thanks

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, a little bit more of research and I found the solution so for anyone interested, you can use this on your functions.php :

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'hide_categories_terms', 10, 3);
function hide_categories_terms($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy){

// define which category IDs you want to hide
$excludeIDs = array(49);

// get all the terms
$exclude = array();
foreach ($excludeIDs as $id) {
    $exclude[] = get_term_by('id', $id, 'event_category');
}

// filter the categories
if (!is_admin()) {
    foreach($terms as $key => $term){
        if($term->taxonomy == "event_category"){
            foreach ($exclude as $exKey => $exTerm) {
                if($term->term_id == $exTerm->term_id) unset($terms[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}

return $terms;
}
```